# How to load a custom module at the boot time in Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, module, linux-kernel, kernel

I created a custom and simple module named Hello.ko
I install the module with the command "**insmod hello.ko**", I check it with "dmesg" and it's working, but when I restart the system, I have to load it manually. So, how can I do for loading my custom module automatically, and where do I have to put the hello.ko?
After loading the module, I would like to show the message **Hello World** until I press the Enter Key. Can anybody help me?

Comment: When you say you want to pause and wait for a key, do you want to do this in text mode amidst low level boot messages, or after the X window system comes up but before you log in?  Do you really need to do this, or is it only to confirm that your module is getting started?  If the latter, just have it printk some messages and check dmesg to convince yourself it's getting loaded at a suitable time.

Answer (score 30):

This technique didn't work on Ubuntu 13.10. So after a few trial and error tries I ended up with this:

Copy my kernel module to the drivers directory.

```
$ sudo cp mymodule.ko /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/
```

Add the simple name of my module to the file /etc/modules. You can edit the file or just append to it as shown here. Please replace `mymodule` to your module's name.

```
$ echo 'mymodule' | sudo tee -a /etc/modules
```

Update the list of module dependencies.

```
$ sudo depmod
```

Reboot the computer and voila, it worked.

Comment: Great! this worked for me too. But I didn't have to put it in the /kernel/drivers directory. I placed it in /lib/module/$(uname -)/initrd.

Comment: In Ubuntu 22 works!

Answer (score 10):

Add the module to the /etc/modules file.

And then put the module in your /lib/modules/kernelname catalogue.

Comment: mmmm do I have to create a folder of just paste it in that location?

Comment: There should be a folder with the correct name (something like /lib/modules/2.6.32-26-generic) just place it there.

Comment: The portable way to refer this path is /lib/modules/\`uname -r\`/